# Comments and replies with Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the SQL database tables **posts**, **comments**, and **replies**

**posts**

| postid | body | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The bucks beat the bills | 1/16 |
| 2 | Soccer tricks and tips | 1/17 |

**comments**

| commentid | postid(references posts.postid) | body | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 78 | 1 | Yayyy | 1/18 |
| 79 | 1 | Booo | 1/19 |
| 79 | 2 | These tips suck | 1/20 |

**replies**

| replyid | commentid(references comments.commentid) | body | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 167 | 79 | I agree | 1/21 |
| 167 | 78 | yayyyy | 1/22 |
| 168 | 79 | No they dont | 1/23 |

I want to do 2 things

## 1

We are GIVEN the postid. For instance, `postid=1`.

In a single call to the database, I want to query the database to GET:

1. the post body
2. the first 2 comments on a post, sorted by created_at
3. for each of those comments, get the first 2 replies, sorted by created_at

Querying POST, COMMENTS, and REPLIES from the database using SQL would look something like,

```
const POST =
    fetch(
         select * from posts
         where postid = 1
    )
```

```
const COMMENTS =
    fetch(
         select * from comments
         where postid = ${POST.postid}
         order by created_at
         limit 2
    )
```

```
const REPLIES =
    COMMENTS.map((COMMENT) => {
        fetch(
             select * from replies
             where commentid = ${COMMENT.commentid}
             order by created_at
             limit 2
        )
    })
```

**How do I write these queries as a SINGLE SQL call to the database?**

The returned data should be in a nested form. Something like

```
const POST = {
    postid: 1
    body: "...",
    comments: [{commentid: 1, body: "..."}, ...]
}
```

But if you have a different form that is easier, I'm open.

## 2

**In the call above, how do I include the **comments** and **replies** aggregates?**

For instance, the returned data should look like

```
const POST = {
    // same as before
    postid: 1
    body: "...",
    comments: [{commentid: 1, body: "..."}, ...]
    // aggregate for comments
    comments_aggregate: 2
}
```

Comment: you join the tables first an can so get all then data for post_id 1, but what do you mean by aggregated?

Comment: aggregated meaning get the total number of comments on a post (the comments aggregate), and the total number of  replies on a comment (the replies aggregate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is incorrect. You cannot reference column `commentid` if it is not unique. Assuming you properly make the `postid`, `commentid`, `replyid` the respective `PRIMARY KEY` of their tables, this method should provide the information you are after.
Few comments inline.

```
SELECT json_build_object(
         'postid', p.postid,
         'body', p.body,
         'comments', json_agg(
           json_build_object(
             'commentid', c.commentid,
             'body', c.body,
             'replies', replies,
             'reply_aggregate', replycount
           )
         ),
        'comments_aggregate', CommentCount
       )
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT postid, commentid, body, created_at, CommentCount
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        /* Count the total number of comments per post */
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY postid) AS CommentCount,
        /* Number the comments of a post to later select the first 2 */
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY postid ORDER BY created_at) as CommentNumber
        FROM Comments
    ) FirstTwoComments
    WHERE CommentNumber <= 2
) c ON p.postid = c.postid
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT commentid,
           ReplyCount,
           json_agg(
             json_build_object(
               'replyid', replyid,
               'body', body
             )
           ) AS replies
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        /* Count the total number of replies per comment */
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY commentid) AS ReplyCount,
        /* Number the replies of a comment to later select the first 2 */
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY commentid ORDER BY created_at) as CommentNumber
        FROM Replies
    ) FirstTwoReplies
    WHERE CommentNumber <= 2
    GROUP BY commentid, ReplyCount
) r ON c.commentid = r.commentid
WHERE p.postid = 1
GROUP BY p.postid, p.body, CommentCount
```

Comment: HOLY COW man, you're insane at SQL. Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I needed.